# List of Classes that failed to compile in ANT

Tags: java, compiler-construction, ant

I have a trivial question for all of you.
I have several build.xml files that compiles hundreds of classes, and whenever I run the build a log file is saved on the server.

Now so far so good, if for example anything fails I can go through the log files... BUT sometime I am faced with many errors, thus scanning through the log file is painful.

I wanted to know if it is possible to say to ant (even at run time) or through the 
**javac** task if it is possible to give a list of classes that failed to compile 
(I do not mean the all error stack but just a list of classes that failed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

--- Edited to include concrete example ---

This example should give you a major head start in logging.  Remember you must add it to your CLASSPATH prior to invoking ant.  If possible, add it to only the CLASSPATH that your copy of ant uses, but wrapping the normal ANT call in a script that sets the CLASSPATH and then calls ANT.

Then run ant with this logger like so

```
ant -logger com.edwinbuck.JavacFileLogger
```

and the following code will produce a list of files that didn't compile.  It makes a number of assumptions (some good, some that might use improvement).

1. It assumes that you must be in the "javac" task to be compiling a java file.
2. It assumes that all non-compiling files emit at least one message of the form '/some/path/to/the/file.java:: description of failure'
3. It assumes that no other javac message contains the character sequence ".javac:"

You will likely have to modify the following code to open a file and write to it, as you see fit.

```
package com.edwinbuck;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildLogger;
import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent;
import org.apache.tools.ant.util.StringUtils;

public class JavacFileLogger implements BuildLogger {

  protected PrintStream out;

  protected PrintStream err;

  protected static final String eol = StringUtils.LINE_SEP;

  private Set<String> errorFiles = new HashSet<String>();

  private boolean ignoringMessages = true;

  public void buildStarted(BuildEvent event) {
  }

  public void buildFinished(BuildEvent event) {
  }

  public void targetStarted(BuildEvent event) {
  }

  public void targetFinished(BuildEvent event) {
  }

  public void taskStarted(BuildEvent event) {
    if (event.getTask().getTaskName().equals("javac")) {
      ignoringMessages = false;
    }
  }

  public void taskFinished(BuildEvent event) {
    if (event.getTask().getTaskName().equals("javac")) {
      ignoringMessages = true;
      // flush the set of files with errors
      for (String filename : errorFiles) {
        out.print(filename);
        out.print(eol);
      }
    }
  }

  public void messageLogged(BuildEvent event) {
    // we don't care about non-javac messages
    if (!ignoringMessages) {
      // error messages have a distinct ".java:" in the line containing the file name.
      if (event.getMessage().contains(".java:")) {
        // just add the (string) name to the set to condense multiple reported errors in the same file
        errorFiles.add(event.getMessage().substring(0, event.getMessage().indexOf(":")));
      }
    }
  }

  public void setErrorPrintStream(PrintStream err) {
    this.err = err;
  }

  public void setEmacsMode(boolean emacsMode) {
  }

  public void setOutputPrintStream(PrintStream output) {
    this.out = output;
  }

  public void setMessageOutputLevel(int level) {
    // this logger ignores message levels
  }

}
```

--- Original post follows ---

Depending on what you want to do, you probably need a custom Ant Listener or Logger.

If you want a Log file that only mentions the failed classes, you can add your own Logger to ant that waits for a `javac` task and then captures the logging events, parses out the failed class names, and appends those to a file.

If you want that information internal to Ant, you can add a Listener which basically collects the necessary data and somehow makes it available to ANT (perhaps by defining a property).

Look to this page on [custom Ant Loggers](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html) to get an idea, and [take note of this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658228/how-to-create-ant-listener-for-specific-task) to see how one listened for a specific task (javac in this case) to automatically run a different task (even when it wasn't specified in the build.xml file).

Comment: thank you, I will let you know ASAP. Well either would be ok, I am just wondering whether which one is the quickest to implement.

Comment: I was reading a few articles, and I ahve just a question.. how would the logger know the difference between an error and simple output? and most of all, how can I parse it?

Comment: You would have to decide if it was error or simple output.  This is typically done by a combination of checking the BuildEvent priority and searching for keywords in the BuildEvent message.  Often you can find a string or substring which helps you find your BuildEvent, I'd imagine it would be something like "error" or "compile failed".  As for parsing it, you would then need to figure out what pattern to "pull" from the string, like the 4th word, the thing between the first set of parenthesis, etc.  If I have time, I'll post an example.

Comment: @7dr3am7, I provided a working example of a Logger that is tuned to collect file names of non-compiled files.  It makes a number of assumptions, which you might have to tune as you align the code with your needs.  Enjoy.

Comment: WOW! thank you @Edwin :$ I wanted to get the answer myself, but that's great

Comment: PS/ @Edwin Buck  I really appreciate it! Question: Where did you learn it? I mean... I even opened a book I had about ANT (ANT: the definitive guide) and couldn't find the properties for failed files in the javac task or I even scanned through the source code :|

Comment: @7dr3am7, there were two problems.  The knowledge of how to log from ANT comes from diving deeper into the resources I presented to you.  The knowledge of what to look for in the messages was trial and error.  Basically, I knew we only wanted javac messages, so I wrote the logger to ignore anything logged outside of a javac Task.  Then I looked at all of javac's message output.  The only one that had the file name it fit a regular pattern that didn't seem to be in other lines (filename:linenum: reason).  Then I found a way to detect that pattern without falsely overdetecting other stuff.

Comment: @7dr3am7, as far as "would the logger know if ...", that would depend heavily upon the message priority.  Basically the logger doesn't know much about a message, except that it has a string "message" and a priority.  The priority is used for filtering (WARN, ERROR, etc).  Sometimes the source doesn't log what you want at the right level (the ERROR level might be that there were compiler errors, while the INFO level might indicate the specific file names).  In your case, I didn't bother checking logging levels.

Comment: :D wow thanks! You must have a very deep knowledge of the source code, because I tried a couple of attempts using the XmlLogger class and a book... and nothing came up, I know what you mean by checking the level, I slightly modified the code introducing:
   `if (event.getMessage().contains(".java:") && event.getPriority() == 0)` in the MessageLogged method

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you grep the file names out of your logs?

A simple example:

```
grep javac build.log | grep java:
```

Comment: Tried - too painful because often you get the whole list or multiple message errors for the same file.

Comment: @7dr3am7 : as you see there are many assumptions made on output from compiler. A script make more easily changeable..  I do that (same as answer), ofcourse with more pipes to make it a unique list

Comment: A script could do, but I would prefer a listener/logger (see answer above) so that I can call it at **run time**