# Parse Ant Script to Analyze in Sonar

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube

Is it possible to analyze an complex ant script (with subant, for instance) with sonarqube without any sonar properties set? Should I parse the script looking for sources, binaries and so on and generate the sonar properties?

My first thought was parse an ant script with Ant's API and extract all information myself.

Comment: I believe that even ant script might be using properties file

Comment: It would help to precise what you are trying to achieve, do you want to raise issues on ant files ? which kind of issues ?

Comment: I had some success using listeners:  Here is a skeletal info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658228/how-to-create-ant-listener-for-specific-task

Comment: @benzonico, I'm trying to generate issues in Sonarqube. It needs to explicitly set the sources and binaries to work. However, I need to do that dynamically.